# Samsung Galaxy Ace - Sim card detection

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-ace, sim-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace android 2.3.7 with cyanogen mod-7-20130301-nightly-cooper version.
It is not detecting the SIM card.

Is it a problem due to Cyanogen mod or something else?